# Can clusterize.js be used with datatables.net?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, clusterize

I load a large amount of data into my tables.
I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to help with search, sorting, pagination, etc. With the large amount of data (and styled rows), it can often take a long time to render in the browser.
Is it possible to use Clusterize.js with datatables.net to improve rendering speeds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, long story short - it's not worth the effort

Since you need such rich functionality as DataTable provides and infinity-scrolling feature Clusterize provides, consider switching to library that has both of these, such as SlickGrid. Despite tha fact that [main repo is abandoned](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid), there are [actively maintaining fork](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid). See [examples](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) I am pretty sure you'll find there what you are looking for.

I know it's not the answer you are waiting for because I know the pain of switching an existing implementation which works, but I don't think anyone will take over the responsibility of combining those two libraries in nearest future.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. "I know it's not the answer you are waiting for because I know the pain of switching an existing implementation which works", you are very correct, I use datatables extensively and it would indeed be painful to switch. I much prefer the documentation and API for datatables than SlickGrid as well. I'll wait and see if anyone else has anything to add before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: I also just found a datatables extrension (https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/), which may perform similar functionality to Clusterize.js

Comment: Cool! Then scroller is best option for you. It's already integrated with datatables, what could be better?
As author of Clusterize.js I will be very surprised if anyone spends his time on what you ask for, because this integration may be tricky, datatables is huge :D

Comment: The author of Clusterize.js seems like an authoritative source to me. I'm accepting the answer but it might be a good idea to update it to suggest the Datatables Scroller extension for those already heavily using datatables rather than SlickGrid. Thanks again for your help.